# What LogParser UI do you use?

Tags: user-interface, scripting, logparser

I just started using [Log Parser Lizard](http://www.lizardl.com/PageHtml.aspx?lng=2&PageId=18) to examine my IIS and Event logs.

What UI tool do you use on top of LogParser 2.2 to view your log files on production?

Answer (score 10):

Microsoft Exchange team just released a new tool,

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/introducing-log-parser-studio/ba-p/601131 ([Archive.org backup link](https://web.archive.org/web/20230000000000*/https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/introducing-log-parser-studio/ba-p/601131))

Answer (score 6):

[Log Parser Lizard](http://www.lizard-labs.net/log_parser_lizard.aspx) GUI, current version 2.5, with its features (even in free version) is still the best GUI for MS Logparser engine available on the market for numerous reasons:

- Query organization: organize queries in multiple groups for quick access.
- Query Editor: syntax highlight, intellisense and tool tips, undo/redo, code snippets and query constants (similar as macro defines in C/C++)
- Great looking Office 2010 style GUI
  -Tabbed results allows multiple queries to be run and compared
- Advanced grid: Excel-style filtering capabilities and the ability to do Averages, Counts, Max, Min, and Sum equations on the fly. Column sorting, rows grouping, showing different views of the data without re-running the query (a big time saver when working with gigabytes of logs). Excel style formulas and conditional formatting are also supported.
- Simple interface for building charts and show result in all kinds of chart types (line, pie, bar, column, doughnut, area, 2D and 3D charts, etc…)
- Print log parser reports
  -Change command line parameters from the GUI
  -Support for multiline (log4net) and regex (regular expressions) input formats and for Т-SQL (OLEDB) queries to maintain your SQL servers from single tool. Also supports Facebook FQL (useful if you are using the tool as Facebook developer).
- Inline Visual Basic .Net code (useful for prompting users for input). Change queries using VB.Net code. For instance this query will prompt the user for EventID input (sample from Lizard Labs web site):

  > select top 100 * from Application  where EventID=<% return
  >   Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Please enter Event
  >   ID","Event ID","1053") %>

And if you really like it, for very small price you can have added value and even more features like export results to Excel 2007, create PDF reports, save queries in centralized SQL Server Database for easy shearing among users , etc…
Therefore I believe that you have made a fine choice using Log Parser Lizard. I believe it is much better software than Microsoft Log Parser Studio and Visual Log Parser or any other logparser GUI I have worked with.

I hope that someday Microsoft will release Logparser 3.0 (that we all love v2.2) supporting more input formats (Exchange, Sharepoint, etc…) and with more powerful features instead of releasing the Log Parser Studio GUI (which is not so bad after all but users have to be informed about better alternatives like Log Parser Lizard here).

Comment: is free and  has portable version ? open source ?

Comment: Its free version is limited to non-commercial use.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly when it comes to Log Parser, I do it CLI, not GUI.  I have not had great need to do lots of parsing (though I probably should since resource utilization is occasionally a problem) so I've always used the SQL-like syntax of LogParser straight up.

Other app teams at my work use [Log4Net Dashboard](http://www.l4ndash.com/), which apparently parses log4net logs, event viewer, and other stuff in one web based interface.  I've not gotten around to checking it out, but other people seem to like it.

For web logs I'm actually starting to look at [awstats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) for my parsing needs so I can see my data in a more visual format.

Comment: Log4Net Dashboard not found

Comment: http://www.l4ndash.com/ not found

Answer (score 1):

I've been using http://en.serialcoder.net/logiciels/visual-logparser.aspx

Comment: http://en.serialcoder.net/logiciels/visual-logparser.aspx not found

Comment: It seems v1.0 is was released in 2006, there were never was any subsequent releases, and it is now dead.